# SQL SELECT transactions for items that two people have both purchased at least once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of `transactions` where a each transaction has a `transaction_id`, an `item` (what item was purchased in the transaction) and a `customer_id` (person who ordered the item).

```
select * from transactions
```

```
transaction_id, item, customer_id
1, Computer, 100
2, Computer, 101
3, Dog, 100
3, Dog, 103
4, Cat, 103
5, Carpet, 101
```

How can I pull all transactions only for items that have been purchased by both customer_id 100 and customer_id 101 at least once? In this case that result would only be the transactions with the item Computer.

Comment: which sql are you using ?

Comment: Have you made *any* attempt at solving this yourself?  If so, what was it, and what problem(s) did it have?

Comment: Using postgresql

Comment: i added the correct tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` if you want only the transactions for those customers:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where customer_id in (100, 101) and
      exists (select 1
              from transactions t2
              where t2.item = t.item and
                    t2.customer_id in (100, 101) and
                    t2.customer_id <> t.customer_id
             );
```

If you want *all* transactions, you could use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when customer_id = 100 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by item) as num_100,
             sum(case when customer_id = 101 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by item) as num_101
      from transactions t
     ) t
where num_100 > 0 and num_101 > 0;
```

Comment: hey how does the second code ensure that it is the same item that has been purchased by both people ? I thought that was the question or am I missing something ?

Comment: @trillion . . . That is what the `partition by item` does.